# Kendo treeview expandPath method

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Kendo has added a new API method called `expandPath` to its treeView in [Q3 2013](http://www.kendoui.com/web/whats-new/release-notes/q3-2013-web.aspx). Unfortunately I can't find any documentation about it in Kendo UI Docs or its forums.

Has anybody used this method? A sample would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it lets you expand a path and provide a callback that is called once all nodes are expanded:

```
var tree = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: [{
        id: 0,
        text: "Furniture",
        items: [{
            id: 1,
            text: "Tables & Chairs"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            text: "Sofas"
        }, {
            id: 3,
            text: "Occasional Furniture",
            items: [{
                id: 8,
                text: "Small Sofas"
            }, {
                id: 9,
                text: "Tiny Sofas",
                items: [{
                    id: 10,
                    text: "Small Tiny Sofas"
                }, {
                    id: 11,
                    text: "Smallest Tiny Sofas"
                }]

            }]
        }]
    }, {
        id: 4,
        text: "Decor",
        items: [{
            id: 5,
            text: "Bed Linen"
        }, {
            id: 6,
            text: "Curtains & Blinds"
        }, {
            id: 7,
            text: "Carpets"
        }]
    }]
}).data().kendoTreeView;

tree.expandPath([0, 3, 9], function() {
    console.log("hello");
});
```

The first parameter is an array of node ids describing the path (in the order you would expand them manually). The second parameter is a callback (this parameter is optional) which is probably mainly useful when additional nodes are loaded from a server (the callback doesn't seem to get called if the last node in the array is a leaf node though).

(see [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/uURiS21x9bAHrcCvOCRM?p=preview))